# Lag a Time Series in R

Tags: r, csv, time-series

I have a column "y1" and I am trying to take the log difference and then find lag 1, 2, 3, and 4.

```
> # Data Import 
> dat <- read.csv("book1.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
> dat
   year Month     y1
1 2000   Feb 125.25
2 2000   Mar 145.23
3 2000   Apr 588.23
4 2000   May 244.12
5 2000   Jun 100.25
6 2000   Jul 585.00
7 2000   Aug 782.25
8 2000   Sep  12.25
> y1 <- dat[,3]       # y1 column
> y1
[1] 125.25 145.23 588.23 244.12 100.25 585.00 782.25  12.25
> dy1 <- c(diff(log(y1))) 
> y11 <- lag(dy1, 1)  # Lag-1
> y12 <- lag(dy1, 2)  #Lag-2
> y13 <- lag(dy1, 3)  #Lag-3
> y14 <- lag(dy1, 4)  #lag-4
> 
> y <- cbind(dy1,y11,y12,y13,y14)
> y
        dy1        y11        y12        y13        y14
 [1,]  0.1480070  0.1480070  0.1480070  0.1480070  0.1480070
 [2,]  1.3987993  1.3987993  1.3987993  1.3987993  1.3987993
 [3,] -0.8794581 -0.8794581 -0.8794581 -0.8794581 -0.8794581
 [4,] -0.8899928 -0.8899928 -0.8899928 -0.8899928 -0.8899928
 [5,]  1.7639448  1.7639448  1.7639448  1.7639448  1.7639448
 [6,]  0.2905625  0.2905625  0.2905625  0.2905625  0.2905625
 [7,] -4.1566484 -4.1566484 -4.1566484 -4.1566484 -4.1566484
```

> 

I was expecting once I take the log difference, the first value would be missing and replaced by "NA". Also, I was expecting the first two value would be "NA" once I take lag-1 for the series and so on. Any help would be appreciated it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `lag` is meant to be used for `ts` (timeseries) objects which are essantially `time->value` mappings. In case of normal `numerics`, there is no `time` data. Therefore the lag will be saved as an attibute.

Comment: @GregordeCillia Thank you! Would you please explain what do you mean. I have displayed the data in a different way. So, please look at it and let me know

Answer (score 1):

You need to append time data to your values in order to use `lag` properly. The shift will then be done in the time component of your time series while the values remain the same. Here is an example.

```
myTs <- ts(dat$y1, start = c(2000, 2), frequency = 12)

myTs
#         Feb    Mar    Apr    May    Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep
# 2000 125.25 145.23 588.23 244.12 100.25 585.00 782.25  12.25

lag(myTs, 1)
#         Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr    May    Jun    Jul    Aug
# 2000 125.25 145.23 588.23 244.12 100.25 585.00 782.25  12.25

lag(myTs, -3)
#         May    Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov    Dec
# 2000 125.25 145.23 588.23 244.12 100.25 585.00 782.25  12.25
```

`lag` is also defined for (`numeric`) vectors, but behaves somewhat different. The shift is saved as an (start/end/stepsize) attribute but the results are rather difficult to use later on (at least for me)

```
y1 <- dat$y1

y1
# [1] 125.25 145.23 588.23 244.12 100.25 585.00 782.25  12.25

lag(y1, 1)
# [1] 125.25 145.23 588.23 244.12 100.25 585.00 782.25  12.25
# attr(,"tsp")
# [1] 0 7 1

lag(y1, -3)
# [1] 125.25 145.23 588.23 244.12 100.25 585.00 782.25  12.25
# attr(,"tsp")
# [1]  4 11  1
```

Comment: Got it ! Thank you so much! It has been a great help !